# Naming Convention For 0.0 - 1.0 Value Range?

Tags: math, terminology

with naming variables i'd like to be as clear as possible.

a percentage can range from 0 and 100.  my public variable only accepts values between 0.0 and 1.0, so naming it a "percentage" can lead to confusion and simply naming it a "value" will not clarify the range limit.

is there a "percent" equivalent or naming convention for variables representing values that range from 0.0 and 1.0?

Comment: What is the actual *meaning* of your variable?  The mere value range won't give you a good name.  (Only thing I can think of from the range alone would be "fraction".)

Comment: the meaning of my variable is a percentage, but acceptable values range from 0.0 - 1.0.

Comment: i'm combining two colors.  a percentage of the second color is added to the first.  the function accepts 3 parameters: mixColors(colorOne, colorTwo, colorTwoPercentage) and returns the result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

0.0 to 1.0 is percentage as well. You didn't get your definition right, a percentage range from 0%  to 100% or from 0.0 to 1.0. It means the same thing, the % means percent = per cent = per hundred.

The range of 0.0 to 1.0 is normally used in statistics, while the range of 0% to 100% is more found in general life as people can put their mind around it better.

Comment: ahh... ok, that makes sense.  i'm a little embarrassed now that i didn't realize that.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a percentage in programming, as that implies a range of 0.0 to 100.0.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It would imply a range from 0.0% to 100.0%, not 0.0 to 100.0. It's either 0% to 100%, or 0.0 to 1.0, which means the same.

Comment: @Femaref What contexts have you seen that define percentage as a number range from 0.0 to 1.0? I've only ever seen it defined as a number expressed as a fraction of 100, in line with its linguistic origin "per cent" or "by a hundred". For example, both [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage) and [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/mathematics/elementary-math/percentages) use this definition.

Comment: all programming contexts, statistics and general calculations. they actually are the same thing: 10% = 10 out of 100 = 10/100 = 0.1. e.g. if you want 10% of 65, you are calculating 0.1*65 = 6.5. percentages expressed as x% are just easier to understand for humans.

Comment: The only reason it is called "per cent" is to specify a context about what an otherwise unit less number means. So `80` means nothing specific. `80 %` means "fraction of 100 = 0.8". So percent and "per one" are different things.

Answer (score 5):

OpenGL uses the "normalized" term for values in the [0, 1] range.