# Percentage stored as a fraction of 1: What is this called?

Tags: naming-conventions, terminology, percentage, fractions

I have a column in a database table called `CONDITION_PERCENT`.

It has values like:

- 1
- 0.1
- 0.01

Which are meant to represent:

- 100%
- 10%
- 1%

---

I suspect that referring to these values as *percentages* might be **incorrect**. Calling them *percentages* certainly seems to be misleading my users (everyone expects the values to be fractions of 100, not fractions of 1).

What is the proper name for percentage values that are a fraction of 1?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this belongs on this website. You'll likely get better answers on the English Langauge forum: https://english.stackexchange.com/

In Any case, I'd personally call them decimals. Seeming as well... they're decimal digits.

Comment: @SimonC : I deleted this question, and tried asking it on [English Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/429261/percentage-stored-as-a-fraction-of-1-what-is-this-called?noredirect=1#comment1029981_429261) instead. But it was immediately put on hold. *"... Off-topic because our Help Center specifically rules the naming of things, including program things like this, to be out of scope for our site."*

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840095/naming-convention-for-0-0-1-0-value-range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the examples you have given, the term you are looking for is "[Decimal Fraction](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/decimal-fraction)" i.e.

> "a fraction whose denominator is some power of 10, usually indicated
>   by a dot (decimal point or point) written before the numerator: as 0.4
>   = 4/10; 0.126 = 126/1000."